# Where to declare Enum

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to use enum WrapMode in two differernt classes.
   what is the best approach.

1) Declare enum in a namespace in a header file and include in both  the classes

2) locally declare the namespace in both the classes separately.

```
enum TextureWrapMode {  Repeat = 0, Clamp = 1};

class My_Texture
 {

 };
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
class Texture
{

 };
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why does it matter how many classes you need to use it in? Do you mean that you have _different_ `TextureWrapMode` enums to declare? Can you explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: i need to use the same enum in differernt classes

Comment: Then simply do so! Did you experience a problem? An error? If so, tell us what it was. Use full, descriptive sentences and quote the compiler's error message. Show us your proper [mcve] not just empty class definitions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Using it in two different classes (in two different files) requires making the definition visible to both. So where should that definition be? That's the question asked here.

Comment: @MaxLanghof The premise of the question is underspecified to be a quality question. It is plainly obvious that such things go in a header just like everything else, and the OP ought to already know this from their basic research. So, if there is a problem, we will need to see the problem. If there is not a problem, we will want to see evidence of research. Either way this is not a good or useful question in its current form. It is also unclear where namespaces come into it, or how you "locally declare the namespace in a class".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, which of the two class headers? Or a separate header? (Or both? I know that quickly leads to ODR violation but that's already quite technical to figure out - having a separate header for each enum definition is quite the bloat and not something I personally see done). I agree this is not a quality question the way it is phrased right now, but the premise is actually valid. Asking beforehand how to do it correctly is better than waiting for and showing a problem because ODR violations are UB, no diagnostic required - you might not get a "showable" problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But yeah the mentions of namespaces are somewhat weird given that they don't appear in the code.

Comment: @MaxLanghof The premise is probably valid, we just don't yet know what it is ;) I am happy for the OP to come forward and to ask us for advice, but I am trying to get them to produce a question we can confidently answer. This isn't it. Frankly I'm baffled by the upvotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged your question c++11: Don't use `enum`, use `enum class`. Namespace issue (and more) solved! Unless I can't use C++11 for some reason, I don't see any reason for using `enum`s anymore.

Other than that, I would put it into a header file if it is used by more than one module.

Comment: Shouldn't the advice to use enum class be like an additional note?

Comment: I don't think so. Although not explicitly asked, I interpreted the question not only as "where should I put the declaration" but also that he'd like to put it into a namespace (very reasonable) and wondered how to do that properly. In that respect, I felt the hint towards enum class was in scope of the question.

Comment: I mean the bit about enum class could be the second part of the same answer (as it doesn't answer the question), the first being that enum should be placed in header.

Comment: You just mean the order? I don't really care about that. In my opinion, both parts answer part of the question, as I understood it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are designing a big project or you have a lot of files where that particular enum is going to be used, so it better to put that enum or, I would say, all the common things like common structure in that .h file and include where you want.

And if you have a single file code that you should declare your enum right after the headers you have declared.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

enum suit {
    club = 0,
    diamonds = 10,
    hearts = 20,
    spades = 3
} card;

int main() 
{
    card = club;
    cout << "Size of enum variable " << sizeof(card) << " bytes.";   
    return 0;
}
```

HOPE IT HELPS

Comment: Two comments/suggestions on this: 1) don't use `using namespace`, 2) in this example, put the `enum` declaration into an anonymous namespace.